# Show private group calendar on other (public) SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, calendar, office-365-groups

We have a public communication site in SharePoint Online. Now we want to display a group calendar (via webpart "Group Calendar") from a private M365 group on this communication site.

Unfortunately users, who are not part of that group, get a message saying they can't see the calendar.

How can we make the calendar public and read only so it displays properly on that communication site?